# Rails Active Record find all including duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I get duplicate posts in my view?

I want to be able to do something like this:

@post = post.find(1,2,1)

to return post 1 , post 2 and then post 1 (again).

realize this is a dumb question but I can't find any documentation.

Comment: What's the use case here? That might help in determining the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Yes maybe this is a bit more complicated than i thought. I have a form and wanted to be able to send an array with values. Do I need to approach this problem in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about the use case you can do something like:

```
@posts = Post.find(1,2) << Post.find(1)
```

of you can define this in your Post model:

```
def find_with_array(*args)
   posts = []
   for arg in args
     posts << Post.find(arg)
   end
   posts
end
```

Obviously the above is inefficient as you are making many SQL calls. If you want it efficient then you can write a code that makes one sql call (but will not return duplicates) and then iterate through the array and rearrange (with copying for duplicates) such as (not fully tested):

```
def find_with_array(*args)
  posts_with_no_duplicates = Post.find(args)
  posts_with_duplicates = []
  for arg in args
    for post in posts_with_no_duplicates
       if arg == post.id
         posts_with_duplicates << post
       end
    end
  end
end
```

This one should be better as you are only making one call to DB (normally slowest part) however it's O(N^2) There might be a way to make it O(N) if need be. However It's great improvement from the previous option

Comment: yes this works, but I wanted to be able to send an array with values.

Comment: thanks a lot Tam, I should really appreciate if you could give me some code example or hints on how to  iterate through the array and copy duplicates if it is something you have in top of your head.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more detail, here's what I would advise. Take a look at this post regarding checkbox arrays: http://www.skuunk.com/2008/05/checkbox-arrays-in-rails.html

Each checkbox drops a value into a particular params key. This will solve the problem of getting an array with a list of values. Let me know in the comments if this doesn't resolve your particular issue.

Comment: yes this is what I have and it works fine as long as I send an array with different values. For example if I have an array with the values ["oranges" , "apples","bananas"] but I want to be able to send an array like ["oranges" , "apples", "bananas","oranges"]. Both the arrays above return the same values using activerecord .find